# How to use 'proc format' to format a missing string, so that can order it at the last of the sequence?

Tags: sas

I have a variable with 3 categories: "Positive", "Negative", ""(missing string).
And I want to sort the sequence with the following order:

```
"Negative" as 1
"Positive" as 2
""(missing value)as 3
```

Here is the code that I used as below.

```
proc format;
    value $rank
    "Negative" = 1
    "Positive" = 2
    "" = 3;
run;
proc sql;
    create table test as
    select *
    from pre_test
    order by subj, lbdat, put(results, $rank.) 
    ;
quit;
```

But the proc format seems has not set the order of missing value into 3, instead, it set order into missing too.
I know that this can be done by using **"if statement"** to create a new variable to accomplish this task. 
But I really want to know, if there are any options to **modify proc format** step to achieve this goal.
**Thank you so much!**

Comment: Does your data have multiple results for a given `subj` & `lbdat` combination ?

Comment: What do you want the format to do when given some other value, like 'Good'?  You probably just want to use `other` category in the format definition that will also capture the all blank values.

Comment: @Tom I want to use this format to order my final datasets with the order:"Negative","Positive" and then the missing values at last. Because simply use order by or proc sort seems can get that sequence.

Comment: So what value do you want the format to create if the input is not missing and not one of the two values you have explicitly listed? If you don't include the OTHER option in your format definition then it will just return the unformatted value.  That will mess up your sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SAS, the missing value for a character variable is a single space.  Change your format to:

```
proc format;
    value $rank
    "Negative" = 1
    "Positive" = 2
    " " = 3;
run;
```

Also, very important to know that character formats (start with `$`) will only map to another character value.  The procedure is implicitly changing your `=1` `=2` `=3` to actually be `='1'` `='2'` `='3'`.

So what is happening when your `FORMAT` step has value

```
`` = 3
```

Because the format name is `$rank` the PROC assumes you will be specifying:

- *character* value-or-range = 'formatted-value'

The double single quotes is interpreted not as a null string, but as a 'bare' character that needs to be implicitly single quoted.  So the procedure is actually processing a value map equivalent to:

```
'''' = '3'
```

Standard string interpretation then reduces the left hand side to a single quote.  This understanding can be confirmed by observing CNTLOUT data.

```
proc format;
    value $myformat
    "Negative" = 1
    "Positive" = 2
    ' ' = 3
    ''  = 4 ;

proc format cntlout=formatdata;
proc print     data=formatdata;
  where fmtname='MYFORMAT';
run;
```

Output

```
Obs    FMTNAME     START       END         LABEL

 1     MYFORMAT                              3
 2     MYFORMAT    '           '             4          <--- Single quote = 4
 3     MYFORMAT    Negative    Negative      1
 4     MYFORMAT    Positive    Positive      2
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to include a space between the quotes to specify the blank value for your format. Without the space it looks like a single quote to PROC FORMAT because it allows unquoted values on the left of the equal sign (just like it allowed the unquoted strings you have on the right side of the equal sign).  But also more importantly you probably want to assign a value for other unexpected inputs in addition to just missing.

But you might want to switch to using an informat so that you can return a number instead of a string. That should be easier to use as an order. Using an informat also lets you have it handle mixed case.

```
proc format;
  invalue rank (default=20 upcase)
    "NEGATIVE" = 1
    "POSITIVE" = 2
    " " = 3
    other  = 4
  ;
run;

data test;
  input @1 raw :$20. @1 rank :rank. ;
  rank2=input(raw,rank.);
cards;
Negative
Positive
POSitive
mixed
.
;
```

Results:

```
Obs    raw         rank    rank2

 1     Negative      1       1
 2     Positive      2       2
 3     POSitive      2       2
 4     mixed         4       4
 5                   4       3
```